# How can I more elegantly remove duplicate items across all elements of a Ruby Array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I want to remove duplicate items within an `Array` object.  It's best to explain with an example.

I have the following `Array`

```
entries = ["a b c", "a b", "c", "c d"]
```

I want a method which will clean this up by removing duplicate items from within elements in the `Array` and return an `Array` which has one element for each unique item.

So here's the method I've written to do this:

```
class Array
  def clean_up()
    self.join(" ").split(" ").uniq
  end
end
```

So now when I call `entries.clean_up` I get the following as a result:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

This is exactly the result I want but is there a more elegant way to do this in Ruby?

Comment: I'd loop over each element splitting them to make one large array of terms then uniq it.

Comment: Do you want elegance or performance?  You can't always have both.

Comment: Both would be nice :) but I've adjusted the wording at the end to focus on a more elegant solution if one exists.

Comment: I think it's a toss-up between what you have and what @muistooshort has suggested. You don't need `self`, which is the default value for the receiver. [Nor do you, μ :-).]

Comment: @EdS., which is more elegant, a Ford or a Chevy?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I can't say that I understand your point.  Just to clarify, I was interpreting "elegance" in the context of how the code looks, not algorithmic elegance.  Maybe I was wrong.

Comment: @EdS., my point, which I could have stated better, was that for some problems, such as this one (imo), there are no elegant solutions, at best well-crafted ones.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: No, `self` isn't strictly necessary but the code I write actually has to be maintained (by me and other people) and I find that explicitly specifying the receiver makes that easier.

Comment: @muistooshort, I respectfully disagree. If you include any unnecessarily element, a less experienced person reading it may well conclude that it's required, and then be flummoxed when they read similar code written by someone else where that element has been omitted. If you don't include `self`, they will quickly find out why, and learn something important in the bargain.

Comment: @CarySwoveland When's the last time you had to dive into an unfamiliar Rails application to fix something? My experience is that many of the common Ruby/Rails practises make maintenance harder than it should be. A test suite helps somewhat but it never covers everything and its utility is limited when it takes an hour to run. The things that work fine for the archetypical 15 minute blog app simply don't work with big complicated apps that are faced with all the usual conflicting constraints. Of course, I'm a natural born heretic.

Comment: As soon as you say you want a more elegant way to do something to working code, your question moves to being on-topic for [codereview.se] instead of Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is for debugging programs, whereas [codereview.se] is for improving working code.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving working code, and belongs on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 1):

[`split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-split) splits on whitespace by default (assuming of course that you haven't done something insane like changing `$;`). You want to split each string and flatten the results into one list, any time you want to "do X to each element and flatten" you want to use [`flat_map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map). Putting those together yields:

```
self.flat_map(&:split).uniq
```

If you only want to split on spaces or don't want to depend on sanity, then you could:

```
self.flat_map { |s| s.split(' ') }.uniq
```

or similar.

Comment: Thanks, that works in that it gives me the result I want.  Can you explain whether it's better than my provided solution in any way besides using `flat_map` which is intended for this kind of operation?

Comment: I like this approach because it is a closer match to the intent, join/split gets the result through trickery rather than a straight forward expression of intent. There's a lot of opinion here of course.