# How would make this more elegant

Tags: ruby

I have this piece of code in an application and was told to make it more elegant but have no idea how to make it better

```
self.join(" ").split(" ").uniq
```

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

self is an array

Comment: Why not **direct** `self.uniq` ?

Comment: Why not just `self.uniq`?

Comment: Well would receive an array like this ["apple orange pineapple", "apple orange"] that's a shortened version it is a lot more entries but similar

Comment: @Droid_Interceptor you should add those details to your question

Comment: Yeah sorry I realized that after posted it

Comment: @Droid_Interceptor you can edit your question :)

Answer (score 1):

`flat_map(&:split).uniq`

- `flat_map` runs a block over an array, and concatenates all the resulting arrays.
- `flat_map(&:split)` is equivalent to calling `s.split` on every argument, which happens to do the exact same thing as `s.split(' ')`, (unless you redefine `$;`, but please don't do that).
- We don't need `self`, so we omit it.

Comment: Or simply `flat_map(&:split).uniq`

Comment: You're correct, split is smart by default, no need to specify a regex.

Comment: Even `self` can usually be omitted

Comment: You should at least include the caveat about [`split`'s default argument](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26317927/479863).